# Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets

I'm working on a project which uses socket programming, but when using the same socket for multiple number of times, even after closing down the `listener()` each time I use the socket: When I run the application it gives the error:

> Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

I am really worried about it. Can somebody help me out?

---

Here is code that i am using, i am closing all connections properly

```
        TcpClient tcpClient;
        TcpListener tcpListener;
        byte[] ipaddress = new byte[4];
        string ip = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IP"].ToString();
        string[] ips = ip.Split('.');            
        ipaddress[0] = (byte)Convert.ToInt32(ips[0]);
        ipaddress[1] = (byte)Convert.ToInt32(ips[1]);
        ipaddress[2] = (byte)Convert.ToInt32(ips[2]);
        ipaddress[3] = (byte)Convert.ToInt32(ips[3]);
        int portNumber = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"]);
        tcpListener = new TcpListener(new IPAddress(ipaddress), portNumber);
        tcpListener.Start();
        tcpClient = new TcpClient();
        tcpClient.NoDelay = true;
        try
        {
            tcpClient.ReceiveTimeout = 1;
            tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            tcpClient.Close();
            tcpListener.Stop();
        }
        NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[networkStream.Length];
        try
        {
            networkStream.ReadTimeout = 2000;
            networkStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            tcpClient.Close();
            tcpListener.Stop();
        }
        string returndata = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes);
        tcpClient.Close();
        tcpListener.Stop();

        return returndata;
```

Comment: Can you post some code and the error you are seeing, please?

Comment: You already asked this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240990 Did no answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are sure that you are picking a port that's unique right?

Have you tried to just use the port once?

Make sure you are truly disposing of connection objects etc before you reopen the socket.  Hard to know without more implementation details.